# Menu filter permission with Laratrust

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, authorization

I'm using AdminLTE and Lara Entrust created a MyMenu Filter.php file to filter my options in accordance with the permission menu.

**adminlte.php**

```
'menu' => [
    'MAIN NAVIGATION',
    [
        'text' => 'Blog',
        'url'  => 'admin/blog',
        'permission'  => 'create-post',
    ],
    // CODE...
 ],

'filters' => [
    // CODE...
    App\MyMenuFilter::class,
],
```

MyMenuFilter.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\Menu\Builder;
use JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\Menu\Filters\FilterInterface;

class MyMenuFilter implements FilterInterface
{
    public function transform($item, Builder $builder)
    {
        if (isset($item['permission']) && \Laratrust::can($item['permission'])) {
            return false;
        }

        return $item;
    }
}
```

My option in the "blog" menu need the create-post permission. But the "if" in mymenufilter.php returns false quando o usuário tem a permissão  and does not create the menu.

But if I put a permission that the user does not have, it appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've just got the logic backwards. You should return false if the user CANNOT use the permission. I have added a ! (not) in the if statement below. This should fix your problem

```
public function transform($item, Builder $builder)
{
    if (isset($item['permission']) && !\Laratrust::can($item['permission'])) {
        return false;
    }

    return $item;
}
```